# Routing Error with Rails 3 Paperclip and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

I followed [this tutorial](http://webtempest.com/how-to-allow-image-uploads-in-rails-on-heroku/) exactly and received the following error after trying to upload a JPG to my local environment (I have not pushed to Heroku yet):

> ActionController::RoutingError (No
>   route matches
>   "/logos/medium/missing.png")

I checked similar tutorials and none of them mentioned requiring routes for your remote images. Like I said, I have triple-checked this tutorial and I'm doing everything it asks of me, so what steps could I be missing here? The ONLY difference is that I already had specified a "photo" column in my model as a binary datatype with the same name as the `has_attached_file` variable...could that be causing the conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to delete this when I realized it will be valuable for others to learn what went wrong.

So if you follow that tutorial to the tee you will do just fine. HOWEVER, if you use `attr_accessible` to protect the attributes of your model, you need to specify ALL of them in your model in order to make these images actually save to your S3 bucket.

A hint will be if you see the following in your logs:

`WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: photo`

This lets you know that you have protected columns in your database that need to be exposed through `attr_accessible`

Here's what the code would look like if you were to follow the example tutorial I provided in my question:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :photo, :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type, :photo_file_size, :photo_updated_at
  belongs_to :page
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles =>{
      :thumb  => "100x100",
      :medium => "200x200",
      :large => "600x400"
    },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
    :bucket => 'yourbucket'
end
```